# Find constant to estimate the norm of a point.

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

How can you find a $C$ such that $C||a+b||_{2}\le||\lambda/x+(1-\lambda)b/y||_{2}$ with $x,y>0 \in \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda \in [0,1]$

Other conditions are $C≠0$ and $||\lambda/x+(1-\lambda)b/y||_{2}≠0$

Comment: Are the twos supposed to be exponents or subscripts?

Comment: They indicate the 2-norm / euclidean norm.

Comment: Can you clarify the conditions here? Are $a, b$ fixed? and what about $\lambda$. Do you want to find a $C$ that works for all $x, y$ or are they fixed too? If all 5 variables have fixed values, then it is just a matter of dividing.